# Diagnosing the cause of slow startup while reloading Pyramid application

Tags: python, performance, pyramid, uwsgi

I have a Pyramid web application running a uwsgi server with touch-reload enabled. If I touch the relevant file to make a graceful restart happen and immediately hit a route in my application it takes about 15 seconds before I get a response. After printing out timestamps at various places in my application I've discovered the following:

- The total execution time of my main method in `__init__.py` is 6 seconds
- The average execution time of my uwsgi post_fork_hook is 2.5 seconds
- The total execution time from the beginning of my main method to the end of the view callable I'm invoking is 9 seconds

I'm wondering how to diagnose where the extra time is being sent since it takes 15 seconds to get a resposne from my application, but it only takes 9 seconds from the beginning of main to the end of my view callable. General tips on how to speed up uwsgi reloads or alternatives to touch-reload are also welcome. Thanks!

Comment: There is a lot of useful info in the debugging panel.  Have you tried it?